# Is someone trying to hack my site?

Tags: security, users

I was looking at my drupal site log messages and I´ve been having very weird ones as the ones attached.

I was wondering if someone is trying to hack my site, if so, how can I prevent that? I have all my site up to date. But it seems I need to take more measures.

thanks in advance[image: screenshot from drupal log messages]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you see in the log is malicious, so: Yes, somebody is rattling the doorknobs on your site to see if some door is not locked.

However, what you see is nothing *unusual*. I think you'll find similar entries in *every* watchdog log for a Drupal site that is "in the wild" (i.e. outside of a firewall).

Should you take more measures? IMHO, no. There is nothing in the messages you've posted that indicates that you're being *targeted*. These are random shots in the dark by script-kiddies - and they're all misses.

One of the reasons we use Drupal is because the core is pretty resistant to this sort of thing out-of-the-box.  Just make sure you keep your site updated. And don't install experimental or badly maintained contributed modules without checking them for security holes yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your answer :), I was getting very concern since I am getting a lot of those messages daily.